# Prove if $|z-1| \le \frac{1}{2}$ then $|\frac{z}{|z|} - 1| \le |z - 1|\sqrt2$ for z complex

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

As the title, problem is to prove if $|z-1| \le \frac{1}{2}$ then $|\frac{z}{|z|} - 1| \le |z - 1|\sqrt2$ for complex $z$.

I noticed using the condition we can get $|\frac{z}{|z|} - 1| \le \frac{\sqrt2}{2}$.

Then can square both sides to get $2(1 - \frac{\operatorname{Re}z}{|z|}$) $\le \frac{1}{2}$.

From here I try further manipulations but am stuck and unable to proceed.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Let $z=re^{i\theta}$,  and then you need to prove $|e^{i\theta}-1|\leq|re^{i\theta}- 1|\sqrt2$. Here $1/2\leq r\leq 3/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$,  and then you need to prove $|e^{i\theta}-1|^2\leq2|re^{i\theta}- 1|^2$. Here $1/2\leq r\leq 3/2,-\pi/6\leq \theta\leq\pi/6$.
$$LHS=2-2\cos\theta;$$
$$RHS=2(r^2-2r\cos\theta+1);$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(RSH-LHS)=r^2-2r\cos\theta+\cos\theta\geq 0.$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $\arg z=\theta.$

Thus, it's enough  to show that:
$$|\cos\theta+i\sin\theta-1|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$ or
$$2-2\cos\theta\leq\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$\cos\theta\geq\frac{3}{4},$$ which is
$$0^{\circ}\leq \theta\leq\arccos\frac{3}{4}$$ or
$$360^{\circ}-\arccos\frac{3}{4}\leq \theta<360^{\circ},$$
which is true because by the given
$$0^{\circ}\leq \theta\leq30^{\circ}$$ or
$$330^{\circ}\leq \theta<360^{\circ}.$$

Comment: Why someone down voted. Explain please.